# Change the font of $\text{}$ within mathmode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, math-operators

In order to exchange the font of my document to Times New Roman, my preamble includes

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
```

(to be quite honest, I'm not exactly sure what the two first packages do).

In any case, in math mode, I frequently use (or define macros containing) `\text{}` to denote operators such as the trace, min/maximum and etc. The problem is that the Times font is ugly for that end (and I suppose the \text{} command simply defaults the argument to the main font).

How do I make `\text{}` return another font -- in particular, the latex default (is it Modern Computer Roman?)?

I'm open to alternative suggestions as to a better practice to replace `\text{}` as I'm using it.

Comment: Firs  line define font encoding, the second one id with use of recent LaTeX version is (last few years9 is not needed any more (is default settings in LaTeX). In math is not recommended to use `\text{...}` command, instead it you should use `\mathrm`. However, for  many mentioned use of `\text` LaTeX define math operators like ˙\min`, `max` etc. For new one you can with help of `amsmath` package define for example for trace `\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}`

Comment: It's been known for decades that Times Roman and Computer Modern don't mesh well at all. Assuming that you have no choice to but use Times Roman as the main text font, is there a chance you could use Times Roman instead of Computer Modern for math mode material? If so, give replacing `\usepackage{times}` with `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` a try.

Comment: @Mico oh, I didn't know that! Thanks! Although I agree that computer modern math is strange in the middle of Times text, I confess that I'm too used to computer modern math to let it go xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be ruling out the possibility of employing a Times Roman-based math font to accompany your document's main text font. If this impression is correct, you should heed @Zarko's suggestion and use `\DeclareMathOperator`, a macro provided by the `amsmath` package, to create "math operators" for items such as "trace". Not only will this give you the desired Computer Modern math font glyphs, it'll also apply spacing rules that are standard for other math operators, such as `\sin` and `\ln`.

Oh, and do yourself a big favor and stop using the deprecated `times` package. Instead, do load the `newtxtext` package. That way, if and when you're ready to take the plunge and can employ Times Roman-based math fonts, all you'll need to do is add the instruction `\usepackage{newtxmath}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for improved handling of words that contain accented characters

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr} % create a new "math operator" (trace)

\usepackage{newtxtext}    % 'times' package is obsolete
%%%\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
$\text{Tr}\mathbf{A}$ vs.\ $\Tr\mathbf{A}$

$\text{sin}\alpha$ vs.\ $\sin\alpha$

$\text{ln}5$ vs.\ $\ln 5$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used to define a macro which contained the correct spacing. This is of course much better. Thanks!

Comment: In any case, for many reasons, it would still be useful to me to have something analogous to the \text{} command within mathmode to get the computer modern text font. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @GaloisFan - Not sure where you're trying to go. As you're aware, the problem with `\text` is that it renders its argument using the prevailing *text font*, which (by assumption) is *not* Computer Modern. Please clarify which use case(s) you have in mind.

Comment: I regularly use sub or superscripts to specialize a symbol. Many times, this is reference to a word, not another mathematical symbol. For example, writing the instantonic part of some lagrangian, I would like to write $\mathcal{L}_{\text{inst}}$. Even though it would make sense to, in this case, have the text as Times, I would still like it to be Computer Modern -- this happens all the time and it cannot be solved by a defined operator. Furthermore, there are math operators with which I don't want standard spacing to follow, such as the form language differential d.

Comment: surely there must be a simple way to render non-italic text in an arbitrary font within math mode.

Comment: @GaloisFan - Thanks for providing this clarification. Give `$\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{inst}}$` a try.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!!!